# munin-run ./<script> gives a different answer than ./<script>

Tags: munin

i am trying to create an arp-scan munin plugin (based on the arp plugin) to find the number of machines connected on my local network.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Plugin to monitor total ARP entries
#
# Parameters understood:
#
# config (required)
# autoconf (optional)
#
# Made by Baziel de Leeuw
#
#%# family=contrib
#%# capabilities=autoconf
if [ "$1" = "autoconf" ]; then
# Search for arp
which arp-scan >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || (echo "no (can't find arp-scan binary)" && exit 1)
# ...or success
echo yes
exit 0
fi
if [ "$1" = "config" ]; then
echo 'graph_title ARP entries'
echo 'graph_args --base 1000 -l 0'
echo 'graph_vlabel Entries'
echo 'graph_category network'
echo 'graph_scale no'
echo 'graph_info This graph shows the number of active ipaddresses registered by the system.'
echo 'entries.label ARP_SCAN entries'
echo 'entries.draw LINE2'
echo 'entries.type GAUGE'
echo 'entries.info Number of active local ipaddresses'
exit 0
fi
ARPENTRIES=$(arp-scan --interface=eth0 --localnet -q -N | tail -1 |rev |cut -f2 -d' '|rev)
let ARPENTRIES=$ARPENTRIES+1
printf "entries.value ";
echo $ARPENTRIES
```

if i run this normally it takes about a second and gives a probable answer (usually 4 or 5 on my system)
if i run this through munin-run it finishes immediately and always gives the answer '1')
like this:

```
[20102 root@server3 plugins]# ./arpscan;munin-run arpscan;./arpscan
entries.value 5
entries.value 1
entries.value 5
```

Does anybody have an idea why this could be? 
This is my first plugin, so it is probably something basic.

Thanks,

Baziel

Answer (score 0):

Issue was a missing part in plugin-conf.d/munin-node
works after adding

```
[arpscan]
user root
```

So it was just missing some permissions. Still weird it gave a wrong answer.